# After span text changed page turns white?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a simple PHP file that takes data and shows it in a table.

When I change the span text with the button, the page turns white. There is no error in the console.
It also happens when I add a function to any button or change something with the script.
Also when I press Submit Button form must be sent and then the page must refresh itself but it returns a white page too.
What could be the problem?

```
<?php
   $connect = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $db_name);
   mysqli_set_charset($connect,"utf8");
 ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<form name="frmContact" method="post" action="denekkayit.php">
    <?php
        $result = mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT * FROM ****");
    ?>
    <table id="example" class="table is-striped" style="width:100%">
            
            <button type="submit" class="mdc-button mdc-button--stroked" onclick="spantext()">
                <i class="material-icons mdc-button__icon">grid_view</i>
                <span id="msg" class="mdc-button__label">Edit</span>
            </button>
            
            <input type="submit" name="Submit" id="Submit" value="Submit">
           
     
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th ></th>
                <th >AAAAA</th>
                <th >BBBBBB</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
             <?php
                $j=0;
                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) 
                {
                    echo
                    "
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td ><input type='text' id='ptwonumber[$j]'   name='AAAA[$j]'  value={$row['AAAA']}></td>
                    <td ><input type='text' id='wonumber[$j]'   name='BBBB[$j]'  value={$row['BBBB']}></td>
                    
                </tr>";
                $j=$j+1;
                };
            ?>
        </tbody>
</table>
</form>

</body>
</html>
<script>
function spantext()
{
    
    if($('#msg').text()=="Edit") 
    {$('#msg').text("Exit")}
    else {$('#msg').text("Edit")}
   
}
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        columnDefs: [ {
            width: 50,
            orderable: false,
            className: 'select-checkbox',
            targets:   0
        } ],
        select: {
            style:    'multi',
            selector: 'td:first-child'
        },
        "scrollY": screen.height/2.2,
        "scrollX": true,
        order: [[ 1, 'asc' ]]
    } );
} );
</script>
```

Comment: HI, when you click on `edit` text gets change but your button has `type="submit"` so your form gets submit .

Comment: It makes sense. Thank you @Swati :)